# Row actions before iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add an action to a row in a tableview (with a swipe). By defect I can use this method to delete:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

But I don't know how to make a custom action. I've read that they introduced it in iOS 11. What if I need it also for a previous version?

Here is the method for iOS 11:

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As you can see I'm using iOS 11. So, to make it clear, I want the user to swipe a row to show an action (with different color background and a text). I don't care form where it appears (trailing or leading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, to make it clear, I want the user to swipe a row to show an action
>   (with different color background and a text). I don't care form where
>   it appears (trailing or leading).

Do this

```
-(NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"  Delete  " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction * _Nonnull action, NSIndexPath * _Nonnull indexPath) {
                // your delete mechanism here
            }];
   deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return @[deleteAction];

    }
```